# What is "all" iterator?

Tags: android, groovy

In the Android plugin for gradle, I wanted to use this method which suggests to use `all` iterator :

```
/**
 * Returns the list of Application variants. Since the collections is built after evaluation,
 * it should be used with Groovy's <code>all</code> iterator to process future items.
 *
 */
 public DefaultDomainObjectSet<ApplicationVariant> getApplicationVariants() {
     return applicationVariantList
 }
```

However, I didn't manage to find any info about this iterator on Groovy official documentation.
Where can I find more info about this iterator ? How is it different from `each` iterator ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally I found where `all` comes from. It is a method from Gradle api : https://github.com/gradle/gradle/blob/master/subprojects/core/src/main/groovy/org/gradle/api/internal/DefaultDomainObjectCollection.java

Comment: An updated link: https://github.com/gradle/gradle/blob/b7d953378b6a7b7a09601f40d3af49d26df49987/subprojects/core/src/main/java/org/gradle/api/internal/DefaultDomainObjectCollection.java#L115

I suspect it could change again in future versions. It seem `all` isn't an iterator at all, but rather a way to associate an `Action` to be applied when object is added in the future.